# issue of accessing $x->output->0->actions as ->0-> does not work

Tags: php, json

Please how can i parse this json response:

```
{ "info": { "apiVersion": "1.1", "clientFeatures": ["all"], "clientTime": "2014-11-27T23:04:27.542Z", "emotions": [], "input": "who+created+you", "isNewUser": true, "locale": "en", "location": "53.0%2C9.0", "login": "mashape", "responseTime": 948 }, "output": [{ "actions": { "custom": {}, "say": {"text": "I was created by the cool guys from Pannous."} }, "entities": { "dialoguesInfo": { "dialog": "Sandbox", "dialog_id": "63", "forced": false, "initiative": false, "match_id": "205233", "matchscore": "3.77", "response_id": "205224" }, "input": "who+created+you", "locale": "en" }, "responseTime": 673, "results": {} }] }
```

I want to get the result in: output->actions->say.

I have already tried : `$req = $response -> raw_body; foreach($req as $ob->$val){}`
but not working.

i have tried `json_decode` too but not working.

Comment: `json_decode()` is your friend.

Comment: Then learn how to use it properly. If it does not work your data is borked.

Comment: Don't be rude, update your question with `json_decode()` results. Also check its contents passing `true` as a second argument which will convert it to array instead of `stdClass` instances.

Comment: @JefferyGintoki talking about rudeness I think one of the rudest things here is to say "it doesn't work" without more details/error messages/etc.

Comment: alright as you can see the json_decode returns lot of stdClasses, i have used one of my functions i did in a CMS i work on to convert stdClass to a simple array but as you can in this json_decode result it returns lot of stdClasses i can't keep calling my function every sec to simplify the object, i'm trying to see if someone can do it easily and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomasz Kowalczyk has already suggested in doing so, `json_decode` is a great native function.

Sometimes it can be frustrating when code does not work the way you expect, but people are really trying to help. When something does not work the way you want, make sure to include **how it did not work for you**.

`$x = '{ "info": { "apiVersion": "1.1", "clientFeatures": ["all"], "clientTime": "2014-11-27T23:04:27.542Z", "emotions": [], "input": "who+created+you", "isNewUser": true, "locale": "en", "location": "53.0%2C9.0", "login": "mashape", "responseTime": 948 }, "output": [{ "actions": { "custom": {}, "say": {"text": "I was created by the cool guys from Pannous."} }, "entities": { "dialoguesInfo": { "dialog": "Sandbox", "dialog_id": "63", "forced": false, "initiative": false, "match_id": "205233", "matchscore": "3.77", "response_id": "205224" }, "input": "who+created+you", "locale": "en" }, "responseTime": 673, "results": {} }] }';`

Than the `json_decode` and a `var_dump` to see the output.

`var_dump(json_decode($x));`

Result:

`class stdClass#1 (2) {
  public $info =>
  class stdClass#2 (10) {
    public $apiVersion =>
    string(3) "1.1"
    public $clientFeatures =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(3) "all"
    }
    public $clientTime =>
    string(24) "2014-11-27T23:04:27.542Z"
    public $emotions =>
    array(0) {
    }
    public $input =>
    string(15) "who+created+you"
    public $isNewUser =>
    bool(true)
    public $locale =>
    string(2) "en"
    public $location =>
    string(10) "53.0%2C9.0"
    public $login =>
    string(7) "mashape"
    public $responseTime =>
    int(948)
  }
  public $output =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#3 (4) {
      public $actions =>
      class stdClass#4 (2) {
        ...
      }
      public $entities =>
      class stdClass#7 (3) {
        ...
      }
      public $responseTime =>
      int(673)
      public $results =>
      class stdClass#9 (0) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}`

As you can see, `json_decode` works fine. For a full summery of the data, instead of `var_dump`, do exactly as above, but use `print_r`.

Remember if you want the decoded data as an array, use `json_decode($yourData, true)`

From here, it should now be very clear, how to access, the data you want. If not, no worries, the solution is close, just write a comment about which parts are confusing you.

*SPOILER*

I added the small snippet for you here https://eval.in/227351 
Basicly the 0 offset is what is giving you a hard time...

`$foo = json_decode($x, TRUE);
var_dump($foo['output'][0]['actions']);`

Comment: bro i was hurry and asked the question wrongly, what i want is to echo out the say results, there is lot of stdClass can't get in there.

Comment: @JefferyGintoki no problem for me. I know what is troubling you, it is the index 0. I will add a spoiler to the answer. Moment... added. Tell me if you think it makes sense. Also, edit you question up, if you got it out there in a wrong way because you where in a hurry, that might reverse some of the downvotes to upvotes.

Comment: thanks lot you are the only one who understand well, thx bro :)

Comment: No problem. If you edit your question, so it suits better (the real probem was the issue of accessing `$x->output->0->actions` as `->0->` does not work. I am sure people will reverse some of their downvotes.

Comment: No problem, last thing, if it is possible, delete the comments that seem rude. That might do the last trick